# How can I run a jquery function to update progress bar when file is uploading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Hello, I am trying to implement some code I got at [http://elfga.com/](http://elfga.com/blog/2012/10/03/bootstrap-progress-bar-update-jqueryajax/). I want to integrate it with the file upload scripts from [AspUpload](http://www.aspupload.com/livedemo.html). I have it working separately but not together.

If I wrap the jquery in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
...
});
```

the jquery runs, polls the script that reports the upload status, and writes to the console as expected. If I bind it to the form submission by using

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#addForm").submit(function() {
    ...
    });
});
```

the file uploads, but the jquery does not poll the script and write the data to the console.

I'm fairly new to jquery. What have I got wrong here?  Thanks

html

```
<form name="addForm" id="addForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="moduleMaterialUpd.asp?PID=368337C0351A5DE6" onSubmit="getProgress()">
<fieldset>
<div>
<label for="title">Material: </label>
<input name="filename" type="file" required/>
</div>
<div>
<input class="button big primary" name="button" type="submit" value="Add Material"/>
<a class="button big primary" href="module.asp?id=456283123">Done</a>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>

<div class="progress progress-striped active" id="progressouter" style="width:500px; margin:10px auto;">
<div class="bar" id="progress"></div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //$("#addForm").submit(function() {
        var request;
        var thispid = "<%=mypid%>";
        console.log(thispid);
        var progresspump = setInterval(function(){
        /* query the completion percentage from the server */
        request = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "progress_ajax_update.asp?pid=<%=mypid%>",
            dataType: "xml"
        });
        // callback handler that will be called on success
        request.done(function (xml){
        $(xml).find('Progress').each(function(){
            var elap = $(this).find('ElapsedTime').text();
            var rem = $(this).find('RemainingTime').text();
            var perc = $(this).find('PercentComplete').text();
            var tot = $(this).find('TotalBytes').text();
            var upl = $(this).find('UploadedBytes').text();
            var rem = $(this).find('RemainingBytes').text();
            var spd = $(this).find('TransferSpeed').text();
            // log a message to the console
            console.log(elap);
            console.log(perc);
            console.log("progress_ajax_update.asp?pid=<%=mypid%>")
            /* update the progress bar width */
            $("#progress").css('width',perc+'%');
            /* and display the numeric value */
            $("#progress").html(perc+'%');
            /* test to see if the job has completed */
            if(test > 99.999) {
                clearInterval(progresspump);
                $("#progressouter").removeClass("active");
                $("#progressouter").removeClass("progress-striped");
                $("#progress").html("Done");
             }
          });
      });
    }, 2000);
  //});
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have given you the clues in an answer below. Try them and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You get this behavior, because when you submit form (by clicking submit button) you actually reload the page or even direct the form submission to another script which in both cases stops javascript interpretation. So to achieve what you want you need to prevent the submission of form before the point you need. Just try to use in your `.submit(event)`:

```
return false;
```

or for latest Chromes I guess (maybe even combine both)

```
event.returnValue=false;
```

You can then check the progress of upload and do something with javascript or when you are happy with upload, then only submit your form in javascript:

```
$('#form-id').submit()
```

But in latter case don't forget to use `.on('click')` handler first on submit button to do what you need, because `$(form).submit()` will simply call again your `submit()` function and which don't return `true` and continue the event.